# Is there a faster way to mirror multi lined text in PHP other than strrev in a loop?

Tags: php, text

I am working with crossword data. What I would like to be able to do is mirror the crossword via the data and not the image. The raw data for the grid layout looks like this

> -----.----.---------.----.--------------.-----------------.....---..-----------.---.---------.-----.-------------------------.-----.---------.---.-----------..---.....-----------------.--------------.----.---------.----.-----

Which forms a crossword when broken up into its size. Its size can be anything, but assuming we give it the input of 15x15 then it would turn into this

```
-----.----.----
-----.----.----
----------.----
-------------..
...---..-------
----.---.------
---.-----.-----
---------------
-----.-----.---
------.---.----
-------..---...
..-------------
----.----------
----.----.-----
----.----.-----
```

That in turn looks like the following

[image: Crossword image]

My goal would be to mirror the text. I know I could create a loop to go through each line and mirror it by using **strrev** to form a new string but I am wondering if there is a **faster method** I am just not seeing.

Comment: Split it into an array of lines, then use `array_map('strrev', $lines)`

Comment: strrev is pretty faster as it is a native php function (so obviously optimized), but why should you loop over each lines instead of apply `strrev()` before you split your text into lines ?

Comment: @EstebanMANSART Mostly because I would then need to get rid of the lines. The data should be 1 line. So make them lines, strrev, combine them into 1 string. 3 steps, or find a faster method. Which is why I came here.

Comment: Clearly you found that your code is too slow. How long does it take now to mirror the crossword, and what execution time would you want to achieve? This will give us an idea about how much faster the answer should be.